# Update 1 record once, and the rest always mysql php

Tags: php, sql-update

I have a query that I'm updating all rows after submit. 
But, I need only 1 record to be updated once (fullname), and the rest always if something changed. How can I do it in my query. I'm working with PHP.

My query:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET customer_name='$customer_name' , country='$country' ,fullname='$fullname' WHERE id = '$id' ";
```